# Error when compiling with iReport-5.6.0 Java

Tags: java, compilation

I have a problem with my report.

It now come to try to make some changes, but it turns out I can not compile the report even without having changed anything.

The error is pulling `iReport`:

> Error compiling the report java source!
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org / eclipse / jdt / internal / compiler / IProblemFactory at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run (IReportCompiler.java:498) at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor $ Task.run (RequestProcessor.java:572) at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor $ Processor.run (RequestProcessor.java:997) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.IProblemFactory at java.net .URLClassLoader $ 1.run (URLClassLoader.java:366) at java.net.URLClassLoader $ 1.run (URLClassLoader.java:355) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader .java: 354) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:423) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:356) ... 3 more
>   Compilation running time: 94

I don't know where this come from, help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use as the netbeans ide and other use iReport program. No more I can compile the report of a project that had done ..