# System.getProperty("java.classpath") = null?

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-errors, jasper-reports, ireport

Hi folks I turn around here and I need you can help me.

It's been a while but I posted this:

[Error when compiling with iReport-5.6.0 Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835175/error-when-compiling-with-ireport-5-6-0-java)

After a while I decided to retry the matter is that it can not compile any report in iReport 5.6.0.

When printing this console in NetBeans:

```
System.out.println (System.getProperty ("java.classpath"));
```

I get null

This case signfica the JAVA environment variable windows is wrong?

What I can do? anyone can help me please.

Answer (score 6):

property name is incorrect, it is `java.class.path`

```
System.out.println (System.getProperty ("java.class.path"));
```

Comment: Right, I was wrong with the code. Thank You

Now tell me how you could solve the problem of my report please if you know this case.

Comment: what is the report problem ?